# What happens to Dispatcher.Invoke if the method to be invoked gets garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispatcher

I have code like this:

```
var myTimer = new Timer(500);
myTimer.Elapsed += (o, a) =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // Handle elapsed
    }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
};
```

If the timer elapses and adds the anonymous method to the Dispatcher, then immediately goes out of scope and gets garbage collected before the dispatcher invokes the anonymous method, what will happen?

Comment: Code doesn't get garbage collected, it only disappears after the AppDomain gets unloaded.  There might be an object of a hidden class underneath if you captured any variables (not in your code), the delegate stored in the invoke queue keeps a reference to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's lifetime won't end specifically *because* the message loop is referencing it.

Even though the object is no longer in scope in code, that object is accessible through a rooted object, so the GC cannot collect it.

The whole point of using managed memory is that you can rely on the GC to only ever reclaim any managed resourced *when it is impossible for them to be accessed from executable code*.  If it's possible for executable code to access an object, then that object will not be collected.

Comment: But the question indicates collection _during_ the event. That probably is possibble but (because) it still has no consequences.

Comment: So the anonymous method created within the scope of Elapsed is considered to be a reference of the timer?

Comment: @HenkHolterman He specifically said that he was wondering if the anonymous method could be collected *after the dispatcher adds the method*.

Comment: @ConditionRacer The anonymous method that you invoke is a local variable of the anonymous method that you assign as the handler to the timer, which is a local variable of whatever scope this whole thing is a part of.  When you add the outer lambda as a handler for the event, or add the inner lambda to the message queue, you're copying references to those created objects to other locations; locations whose lifetimes may be different than that of the local variables that the object instances were originally assigned to.